# Cartoon/anime show involving a guy duped by the immortal bad guy, a green stone that gives pain powers, and a blue stone for super strength

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

They wear the shirt color of their gems, and they fly all over the world in a jet looking for other people who have gems.

The bad guy tricks the first character to take his side and later finds out he is an immortal bad guy.

The first character we meet has a green stone that allows him to inflict pain on others. He wear a green shirt and jeans. Later, he finds out he can also remove pain from other people. He is also wheelchair-bound from a wreck and is hospitalized along with the guy who caused it

A guy with a blue stone embedded into him has supernatural strength. He wear a blue shirt and jeans

Comment: Welcome to Scifi & Fantasy. Could you think of any other details you could add (such as how the characters look like, the setting, etc.)? Also, could you recall when you watched this cartoon/anime?

Comment: I want to say it was on Netflix 2015 or 2016

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*The 99*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_99_(TV_series)) (2011).

There's a heavy emphasis on gem-based magical powers, including a gem that can cause and relieve pain. Note that the main character is in a wheelchair.

> Episode 1: A man called Doctor Ramzi Razem, Noora the Light and Jabbar
> the Powerful recruit Darr. Darr survived a car accident caused by
> William Danford, but it killed his parents. Darr learns to not only
> afflict pain but also to relieve pain.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Comment: @HJC - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)