# Cartoon show similar to X-Men, with magic stones (it was on Netflix in the 2000s)

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

A man goes around finding kids and adults with magic stones. One of the kids is about 12 years old, but is built like a grown man, and is super strong, and has a blue gem inside of him. Another person has a green gem, I think, and is in a wheelchair; he is telekinetic.

Comment: Netflix only offers streaming since 2007, and internationally since 2010.

Comment: Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236938/cartoon-anime-show-involving-a-guy-duped-by-the-immortal-bad-guy-a-green-stone - which has an accepted answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartoon/anime show involving a guy duped by the immortal bad guy, a green stone that gives pain powers, and a blue stone for super strength](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236938/cartoon-anime-show-involving-a-guy-duped-by-the-immortal-bad-guy-a-green-stone)

Comment: It appears this question has neither an answer nor a confirmation from the OP.

Comment: I've added an answer that can possibly be accepted, although it is not yet.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the answer linked above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236938/cartoon-anime-show-involving-a-guy-duped-by-the-immortal-bad-guy-a-green-stone), there's a good chance this is the 2011 animated series, *[The 99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_99_(TV_series))* (synopsis from [the comic book it's based off of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_99)).

> The 99 are ordinary teenagers and adults from across the globe, who come into possession of one of the ninety-nine magical mystical Noor Stones (Ahjar Al Noor, Stones of Light) and find themselves empowered in a specific manner. All dilemmas faced by The 99 are overcome through the combined powers and capabilities of three or more members. Through this, The 99 series aims to promote values such as cooperation and unity throughout the Islamic world. Although the series is not religious, it aims to communicate Islamic virtues which are, as viewed by series creator Dr. Al-Mutawa, universal in nature.

The fellow in the wheelchair is Darr the Afflictor. The big guy is Jabbar the Powerful.

### A clip of Episode #1 from the official YouTube channel