# Old cartoon sort of like X-men with gemstones of power

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I just remembered this cartoon a while back, I watched it on Netflix in the late 2000s, early 2010s.

It was about people who got gemstones that gave them power. The only way to be unbound to the gemstone was to die.

There was a Reginald Hargreaves/Professor X-type guy that we follow throughout the first season and then he turns out to be the evil guy. It was sort of like X-men with gemstones.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did this cartoon feature 2D or 3D animation? Also, what did the "Reginald Hargreaves/Professor X-type guy" look like? For example, was he bald or did he have hair? If he had hair, what colour was it? Did he have facial hair? Did he wear glasses?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

If the cartoon you're looking for was 3D-animated, this might be ***[The 99](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2242637/)*** (2011–2012).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_99_(TV_series)):

> *The 99* is a 2011–2012 animated series directed by Dave Osborne and based on the [comic book series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_99) created by Naif Al-Mutawa.
>
> The series was planned to air on the TV channel *The Hub* in the United States, but didn't make it due to controversy.

From IMDB:

> 99 youngsters from across the globe, 99 ancient Noor stones, 99 superpowers. Ramzi wants them to do good for mankind, but Rughal has other ideas.

The show features a team of X-Men-like teenagers, granted different powers by 'ancient Noor stones,' and they're led by a Professor X-like figure in [Dr. Ramzi Razem](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/dr-ramzi/4005-72527/). Ramzi isn't a villain, but in the first few episodes, he's impersonated by the actual villain, Rughal. This fact is revealed at [the end of episode 3](https://youtu.be/EdKZMPkH580?list=PLF7gb5h94nIec-OeoBKxY6osjCE__AKnU&t=1326).

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/236938/23243.