Old animated show about magic stones from the lost library of Alexandria?
I remember watching this show on Netflix when Netflix was young, but the show was from the 80s or 90s. The show was about these adults who were 'chosen' by these magic stones that gave them super powers. The show was a reflection of real world struggles too.
The series mainly revolved around this MIB-esque guy rounding up all the super stone people and putting them on a team to help humanity.
There was a man who was hit by a drunk driver and was left paralyzed. He was hospitalized in the same room as the drunk driver, who was left in a coma. The man got one of the magic stones, and this stone gave him the power to either heal or hurt with his mind. He was so hurt after losing his ability to move around that he, without knowing, kept the driver in the coma with his new stone powers. He has this arc where he learns to forgive and use his powers only to heal, however he could never heal himself. He is wheelchair bound for the entire series.
I also remember there was a woman boxer who had a stone that gave her super strength or indestructability, can't recall which.
There was also a young man who was being held captive for his super intelligence powers given to him by his stone. He was literally a living computer, wired up with cables from his brain to machines. When the MIB guy came to save him, there was the problem that the machine would kill the young man if he even thought about removing the cables from his head. So the MIB guy was like, well just don't think about rabbits then. And he just ripped the cables out as the young man puzzled about rabbits.
I really want to find this show and revisit it. It was so strangely grounded and empathetic. I remember being so upset when it was taken off Netflix and even more frustrated that I couldn't remember what the show was called (I was like 14 then). Any ideas?

If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

As per Animated show where characters had crystals on their bodies that gave powers, The 99


The 99 are ordinary teenagers and adults from across the globe, who come into possession of one of the ninety-nine magical mystical Noor Stones (Ahjar Al Noor, Stones of Light) and find themselves empowered in a specific manner. All dilemmas faced by The 99 are overcome through the combined powers and capabilities of three or more members. Through this, The 99 series aims to promote values such as cooperation and unity throughout the Islamic world. Although the series is not religious, it aims to communicate Islamic virtues which are, as viewed by series creator Dr. Al-Mutawa, universal in nature.

The man in the wheelchair is Darr, introduced in the first episode. The female boxer would be Hammerforce.
Episode 01 from the official channel




If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236938/cartoon-anime-show-involving-a-guy-duped-by-the-immortal-bad-guy-a-green-stone

I don't think the stones are ever stated to be from the Library of Alexandria, but I'll admit I've never actually watched the series. I've just provided it as an answer before.
